# Django page not found 404, Raised by: blog.views.blog_postDetailView

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

sometimes when i want to open the about page, the contact, create or blog
page this error comes: Raised by:   blog.views.blog_postDetailView
i donnt know why, but I think it has to do sth with my urlpattterns
or the order of them . here my code.
appreciate your help and improvements
thanks a lot

mainurl

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin


from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from blog.views import AboutPageView, ContactPageView, blog_postCreateView

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/', ContactPageView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    url(r'^create/', blog_postCreateView.as_view(), name='blog_post_create'),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

   #admin and login
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
   url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

blog url

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import blog_postListView, blog_postDetailView, blog_postCreateView 

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', blog_postListView.as_view(), name='blog_post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', blog_postDetailView.as_view(), name='blog_post_detail'),
]
```

base html, the nav part

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a></li>
            {% endif %}
```

model

```
rom __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.





def upload_location(instance, filename):
    #filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    #return "%s/%s.%s" %(instance.id, instance.id, extension)
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.id, filename)


class blog_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True, width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    #height_field = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    #width_field = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title   

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog_post_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = blog_post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)



pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=blog_post)
```

views

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator




from .models import blog_post
from .forms import blog_postForm
# Create your views here.


class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
     @classmethod
     def as_view(cls, **kwargs):
       view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**kwargs)
       return login_required(view)

    #@method_decorator(login_required)
    #def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)



class blog_postCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    #model = blog_post
    form_class = blog_postForm
    template_name = "form.html"
    #fields = ["title", "content"]
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("blog_post_list")

    # @method_decorator(login_required)
    # def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #   return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)    


class blog_postListView(ListView):

    model = blog_post
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(blog_postListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).order_by("-timestamp")
        return qs

class blog_postDetailView(DetailView):

    model = blog_post

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "about.html"


class ContactPageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "contact.html"
```

updated urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin


from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from blog.views import AboutPageView, ContactPageView, blog_postCreateView

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/', ContactPageView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    url(r'^create/', blog_postCreateView.as_view(), name='blog_post_create'),
    url(r'^categories/', include('blog.urls_categories')), 
    #url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

   #admin and login
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
   url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
   url(r'', include('blog.urls')),

]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the below line in end of `url_patterns` list like

```
urlpatterns = [
     #all other urls, 
     url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

**OR**

```
url(r'^blogdetail/', include('blog.urls')),
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help,
all pages work, except the create and "blog" page,
could you please be so kind and explain why it should work then,
cause of changing the order or instead of blog use blogdetail, what what be the template tag for the blog link  ? thanks alot

Comment: ok thank you, like this order it works fine for me :)
i posted the updated urls above, could explain why it works,
when i put the url in the end?

Comment: yep :), but I would love to understand , why it works when i change the order and put the below line in the end,

Comment: django will look for the url in the list one by one. So your 'url(r'', include('blog.urls'))` is ready to accept anything. Also inside `blog/url` it is `regex` there (`(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$`). So almost every url will eat this line :p.

Comment: Ok i understand, thanks for explaining, have a nice day